# When will the iOS apps be updated?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It would be great in particular to have them support the iPhone X display.

Comment: AFAIK active development is on hold so don't expect anything in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @rene why is that?

Comment: @Maroun I can only guess but I think a focus on the core product (Q/A, Channels / Jobs) that should bring in money. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/158100

Comment: Just fill the spaces that are currently black bars on the iphone X with advertising banners.. problem solved! (i'm joking, please don't do this).

Comment: It would be even greater to at least have a fix for the blank screen on commenting and paste issues, but I guess that's also too much to do :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From a [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303184/295232) answer by [Brian Nickel ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel), Stack Overflow's iOS app developer:

> TL;DR: When active app development resumes, this will be a top priority, but there's really **no timeline for when that will happen**.
>   ...
>   The good news is there's really no path forward with iOS development that doesn't involve supporting the X, so when development resumes it'll need to be the top priority.

(emphasis mine)